# Aurelia error on catch - Invalid resource path

Tags: try-catch, aurelia

My aurelia application stopped working since the 2nd of July with this random error on the catch of:

```js
aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot()).catch(reason => console.log(reason));
```

> Error: Invalid resource path [function RouterView(element, container, viewSlot, router, viewLocator, compositionTransaction, compositionEngine) {

```
  _initDefineProp(this, 'swapOrder', _descriptor, this);

  _initDefineProp(this, 'layoutView', _descriptor2, this);

  _initDefineProp(this, 'layoutViewModel', _descriptor3, this);

  _initDefineProp(this, 'layoutModel', _descriptor4, this);

  this.element = element;
  this.container = container;
  this.viewSlot = viewSlot;
  this.router = router;
  this.viewLocator = viewLocator;
  this.compositionTransaction = compositionTransaction;
  this.compositionEngine = compositionEngine;
  this.router.registerViewPort(this, this.element.getAttribute('name'));

  if (!('initialComposition' in compositionTransaction)) {
    compositionTransaction.initialComposition = true;
    this.compositionTransactionNotifier = compositionTransaction.enlist();
  }
}]. Resources must be specified as relative module IDs.
at FrameworkConfiguration.globalResources (browser-index.ts:30)
at Object.configure (browser-index.ts:30)
at browser-index.ts:30
at tryCatch (browser-index.ts:30)
at invokeCallback (browser-index.ts:30)
at publish (browser-index.ts:30)
at MutationObserver.flush (browser-index.ts:30)
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error. Didn't fully get to the bottom of it but it seems to be related to aurelia-templating-router@1.3.2 and aurelia-templating-resources@1.7.0 which have been published 2 and 3 days ago.

Once I installed aurelia-templating-router@1.3.1 and aurelia-templating-resources@1.6.0 my app came back to life

Comment: Thanks. I will check that out and give some feedback today.

Comment: Pegging these packages to the versions specified here worked for me.  That was a simple end to a rather frustrating day of debugging.   I'm unclear as to how this also just started happening for us given that I had a `package-lock.json` file that was pegging aurelia-templating-router@1.2.0 and aurelia-templating-resources@1.5.0.  Perhaps my lock file was being ignored for some reason.  I sure do hate the javascript ecosystem!